# $a(f(y+\epsilon)-f(y))<(f(x+a)-f(x))(1-a)$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

$f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is an increasing and continuous real function. $a>0$, $\epsilon>0$ are small positive numbers.

Is it correct that: for some $x$ and $y$, $\exists\epsilon\forall \delta>0$ there exists $a<\delta$ s.t.

$a(f(y+\epsilon)-f(y))<(f(x+a)-f(x))(1-a)$.

---

The inequality looks obviously correct as we can simplify the inequity if $f$ is differentiable:

Step (1): $f(y+\epsilon)-f(y)+f(x+a)-f(x)<\frac{f(x+a)-f(x)}{a}$

Step (2): $\epsilon f'(y)+af'(x)<f'(x)$

Step (3): Just take $a,\epsilon$ both to be very small then the inequality holds.

But I am not sure how to simplify and solve this question when $f$ is not differentiable.

---

**Example**: When $f(x)=x$, the inequality simplifies to $-1+a+\epsilon<0$ which is obviously correct.

Comment: What is  the domain ?  Are $x$ and $y$ fixed? Your argument for the case when  $f$ is differentiable  is not valid if $x$ and $y$ are variables

Comment: I cannot parse the line that starts "prove that". Is it correct?

Comment: @Blitzer The grammar should be fine.

Comment: Note that a previous version of the question is invalid thanks to Rondoudou

Answer (score 1):

The property you want to show is false if you consider a function $f$ such that, on some interval $I$, $f$ is constant, while it is not constant everywhere.

Indeed, in that case, choose $x \in I$ (in the interior actually) so that for small enough $\delta > 0$, any choice of $a$ will make the right-hand side $0$ ; if $y$ is a point where $f$ is not locally constant, clearly the left-hand side will be strictly positive.

If by "increasing function" you mean "strictly increasing function", it still remains false. You can simply consider a differentiable function $f$ such that $f'(x) = 0$ and your approximation argument fails : indeed, if $f(x+t) = c_1 + t^3$ locally around $x$, while $f(y+t) = c_2 + t$ locally around $y$, you ask for :

$$ a \varepsilon < a^3 (1-a) $$

for a fixed $\varepsilon$ and $a$ arbitrarily small, which cannot hold.

Comment: Actually not. $t \mapsto t^3$ is strictly increasing on $\mathbb{R}$ but its derivative is $0$ at $t = 0$.

Comment: You are right. Is it possible that the statement is correct whenever $f'(x)>0$?

Comment: Well, if you choose $x$ such that $f$ is differentiable at $x$ and $f'(x) > 0$, then your proof holds (even if $f$ is not differentiable at $y$ actually, all you need here is continuity at $y$).

Comment: I guess, to make the statement, I need to change "for any $x,y$" to "for some $x,y$". But this change will turn your answer invalid so I am hesitating.

Comment: It depends on the problem you're considering. Perhaps the function $f$ can be assumed to be strictly increasing, differentiable and satisfies $f' > 0$ : but as it is stated it cannot hold.